# Searching in unanswered category

Tags: support, search, tag-search

Scenario:

1. Go to Unanswered button that is on side of Badges.
2. Search for any tag. For example: [java]
3. You will be redirected to newest question tab for Questions category.

Searching for a tag in Unanswered category takes you to the Questions category. Why?

Comment: Banner button [Unanswered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) returns a list of unanswered *questions*.  As @Bill explains you need to click on the *unanswered* sub-tab of search results to obtain the desired behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps 1 and 2 are independent of each other.  Searching takes you back to the Questions category on the last tab you had selected.  You just happened to have selected the new tab most recently.  Just click on the unanswered tab.

Comment: Can it be possible to remain in Unanswered category?

Comment: Yeah, if you click on the unanswered tab first, then search.

Comment: I believe, if you search while on the unanswered tab, it still returns search results *with* answers.  [Hence my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98758/auto-add-answers0-when-searching-from-unanswered-tab)

Comment: Of course you can click on the [unanswered tab within the search results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50), but in testing it just now, this doesn't come up by default after clicking on the main **Unanswered** button in the top banner.

Comment: @M.Tibbits: That's not the same thing.  See my answer to your question.  Clicking the Unanswered button is a separate action from searching.  There's no reason to think that it would affect your search results.

Comment: I apologize - you are correct, not the same thing - I've removed my answer; however, I disagree with your assertion that there's no reason to think it would affect your search results -- when browsing within the Unanswered context, why not 'by default' return the unanswered results??  I see this as similar to the thinking that searching on Stack Overflow does not return results from ServerFault.

Comment: @M.Tibbits: It's just a different thing altogether.  When you click the Tags, Users, or Badges buttons you don't expect that to have any impact on your later search results either.  The buttons at the top just take you to different areas of the site.  Searching takes you back to the Questions view.

Comment: @Bill, I understand.  Perhaps better phrased, my question is, *Why not make the default search behavior more context sensitive?*  I believe this is the OP's intent?

Comment: @M. tibbits: Yes.