# Auto-add 'sort=unanswered' when searching from Unanswered tab?

Tags: feature-request, search-engine

Given [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98755/152009/), would it be possible to automatically add **sort=unanswered** whenever a search is initiated while browsing the [Unanswered](http://www.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab?

**Update:** Sorry for my confusion, I had posted this requesting 'answers:0' which *is not* the same as unanswered.  Thank you for clarifying @Bill & @ChrisF.

**Update 2:** Note that my request pertains to Stack Overflow, as I've now realized that the default searching behavior is different from that of Meta.  These two actions take the user to different places within the UI:

- [Click on the Meta Unanswered tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) and search for java.
- [Click on the Stack Overflow Unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) and search for java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**answers:0** is not what "Unanswered" means on Stack Exchange.  "Unanswered" means there have been no *upvoted or accepted* answers posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can already do this.

Use the "No Answers" tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers